# When to use deleteOnExit and not delete?

Tags: java, io

First of all I am not asking for difference between the two. I am wondering what     will be a scenario where one will choose to use `deleteOnExit()` over `delete()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sometimes we may want to create temporary files to save some data that gets written by an application or to temporarily store some data for use in the near future by this same application, etc. etc. In these scenarios, we may do something like this:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(...);
tempFile.deleteOnExit();
.... // the rest of the code
```

Answer (score 0):

deleteOnExit would be appropriate for temporary files you'd like to be cleaned up on exit